# Solidity- How To test Struct arr in foundry

Tags: solidity, unittesting, foundry

```
//Here I have created one struct with different parameters such as address , uint, bool ,uint 
//and in this array i have pushed some values in submitTransaction function and it is working as expected  
struct Transactions {
    address to;
    uint256 _value;
    // bytes data;
    bool isExecuted;
    uint256 numOfConfirmation;
}

Transactions[] public transactionArr;

function submitTransaction(uint256 _value,address _to) public onlyOwner returns(bool success){

    uint txIndex  = transactionArr.length;

    transactionArr.push(Transactions({
        _value:_value,
        to: _to,
        isExecuted:false,
        numOfConfirmation:0
        }));
    

    emit submitTransactions(_value, txIndex, _to);

    success = true;
    
}
```

Here is test function of this submitTransaction function where i'm trying to get the value of struct array

```
function testSubmitTransaction() public {

multiSigWalletObj.submitTransaction(1000,0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC);
    (,uint value,,) = multiSigWalletObj.transactionArr._value;
    assertEq(value, 1000);
    emit log_named_uint("The Value in submit Transaction is: ", value);
}
```

And getting this error

```
Compiler run failed
error[9582]: TypeError: Member "_value" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function (uint256) view external returns (address,uint256,bool,uint256).
  --> test/MultiSigWallet.t.sol:21:27:
   |
21 |         (,uint value,,) = multiSigWalletObj.transactionArr._value;
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `multiSigWalletObj.transactionArr` as it were a data member, but it is a getter because `transactionArr` is an array in the contract.

You need to call with the array position `multiSigWalletObj.transactionArr(0)`.